# Galaxy tab 4 7.0 version 4.4.2 stuck in Odin Mode

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-tab, odin

Today I would like to root my samsung galaxy tab 4 7.0 version 4.2.2. while odin running, it display fail and then my phone now is stuck in odin mode..

Please see my photo :

Odin Mode Product Name: SM-T231 Current Binary: Custom System status: official. [image]

please help[image]

Comment: Can you boot into recovery? I assume you have a custom recovery? Your current binary says custom.

Comment: How to boot into Recovery? because I try to press column down + home Button + power button and i try to press column up + power button + home button, but can't solve my problem.

Comment: How about just Volume Up + Power?

Comment: Volunm Up + Power also can't solve problem :(

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm... seems like you're stuck. Ok so solution is to download the stock firmware and flash your device vis odin.  Thats how I got mine fixed. Sm t231.